# A problem possibly about the Whitney Embedding Theorem.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

**Problem.**

(1) Suppose $F:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth immersion (i.e. $dF$ is nowhere zero). Prove that there is a unit vector $\mathbf v$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\pi_{\mathbf v} \circ F : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is also a smooth immersion, where $\pi_{\mathbf v}$ is the orthogonal projection to the vector subspace which is orthogonal to $\mathbf v$.

(2) Show by example that there is such an $F$  that is infective but for all $\mathbf v$ ,  $\pi_{\mathbf v} \circ F : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ fails to be injective.

*Remark:*Personally, I think this problem must be related to the following lemma (cf.GTM 218 Introduction to Smooth manifold), which is for Whitney Embedding Theorem. 
But, here the dimension condition in the lemma $N >2n+1$ doesn't hold.

As in the lemma, to show there is a $\pi_{\mathbf v}$ is an immersion, it suffices to show the following map
$$ \tau : TM \smallsetminus M_0  \to RP^2 $$
is not surjective, where $M=F(S^1)$. However, I cannot continue.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your title please.

Comment: Try fiddling with the lemma. What you lose here is not the immersion property, but rather injectivity.

Comment: Is it equivalent to show $S(TM) \to RP^2$ cannot be surjective, where $S(TM)$ is the unit sphere bundle of $TM$?